# '&' : illegal operation on bound member functions expression Thread

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm trying to run a member function in a thread, but I get the error illegal operation on bound member function, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I would like if someone could explain me what I'm doing wrong and why I get this error, and give me an example of how to fix it. The code looks like this:

```
void GameWorld::SetupWorld()
{
    // create the window (remember: it's safer to create it in the main thread due to OS limitations)
    RenderWindow window(VideoMode(800, 600), "OpenGL");

    // deactivate its OpenGL context
    window.setActive(false);

    // launch the rendering thread
    Thread thread(&Render, &window);//This line gives the error
    thread.launch();
}

void GameWorld::Render(RenderWindow* window)
{
    Texture texture;
    Sprite sprite;

    if (!texture.loadFromFile("sprite.png"))
    {

    }

    sprite.setTexture(texture);

    // the rendering loop
    while (window->isOpen())
    {

        // clear the window with black color
        window->clear(Color::White);

        // draw everything here...
        window->draw(sprite);

        // end the current frame
        window->display();
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the full error message given by your compiler. Is `GameWorld::Render()` declared `static`?

Comment: You dont need the address ('&') for the function or the input variable. You can call it like this:  `Thread thread(Render, window);`

Comment: To get a pointer to member function you must do `&GameWorld::Render`. However it seems very unlikely that `Thread` (whatever that is) is going to work with a pointer-to-member-function with no associated object.  You will need to make `Render` static . (and not give it a reference to a destroyed object!)

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37815641/visual-studio-2015-non-standard-syntax-use-to-create-a-pointer-to-member

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a serious case of [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) from passing a pointer to a local variable to the thread.

Once the function returns, that variable will go out of scope, and the object will be destructed, leaving you with a pointer to unallocated memory.

---

You also have a problem if the `Render` function is not `static`, because non-static member functions have a hidden first argument that becomes the `this` pointer inside the member function. It's probably this problem that the compiler is complaining about.

---

A possible third problem might be that once the `SetupWorld` function returns, your `thread` variable will *also* go out of scope and be destructed. Depending on what threading framework you're using it might kill the thread quite unexpectedly.

Answer (score 1):

To fix the compilation error change your complaining line to `Thread thread(&GameWorld::Render, &window)`

However for completeness you should read @Some programmer dude's answer.