# Accessing a variable of passed by reference object in passed by reference object

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference

It took me a while to think how to ask this question. The code is too big, so I will try to take only the important parts.

```
    class full_object_detection
{
public:
    full_object_detection(
        const rectangle& rect_,
        const std::vector<point>& parts_
    ) : rect(rect_), parts(parts_) {}

    full_object_detection(){}

    explicit full_object_detection(
        const rectangle& rect_
    ) : rect(rect_) {}

    const rectangle& get_rect() const { return rect; }
    rectangle& get_rect() { return rect; }
    unsigned long num_parts() const { return parts.size(); }

    const point& part(unsigned long idx) const 
    { 
        // make sure requires clause is not broken
        DLIB_ASSERT(idx < num_parts(),
            "\t point full_object_detection::part()"
            << "\n\t Invalid inputs were given to this function "
            << "\n\t idx:         " << idx  
            << "\n\t num_parts(): " << num_parts()  
            << "\n\t this:        " << this
            );
        return parts[idx]; 
    }

    point& part(unsigned long idx)  { 
        // make sure requires clause is not broken
        DLIB_ASSERT(idx < num_parts(),
            "\t point full_object_detection::part()"
            << "\n\t Invalid inputs were given to this function "
            << "\n\t idx:         " << idx  
            << "\n\t num_parts(): " << num_parts()  
            << "\n\t this:        " << this
            );
        return parts[idx]; 
    }

    friend void serialize (
        const full_object_detection& item,
        std::ostream& out
    )
    {
        int version = 1;
        serialize(version, out);
        serialize(item.rect, out);
        serialize(item.parts, out);
    }

    friend void deserialize (
        full_object_detection& item,
        std::istream& in
    )
    {
        int version = 0;
        deserialize(version, in);
        if (version != 1)
            throw serialization_error("Unexpected version encountered while deserializing dlib::full_object_detection.");

        deserialize(item.rect, in);
        deserialize(item.parts, in);
    }

    bool operator==(
        const full_object_detection& rhs
    ) const
    {
        if (rect != rhs.rect)
            return false;
        if (parts.size() != rhs.parts.size())
            return false;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < parts.size(); ++i)
        {
            if (parts[i] != rhs.parts[i])
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

private:
    rectangle rect;
    std::vector<point> parts;  
};
```

---

```
typedef vector<long,2> point;
```

---

```
const full_object_detection& d = dets[i]; //Passed by reference object
```

**Output of:**

`cout << d.part(41) << endl; // (123,456)`

`cout << d.part(41).x << endl; // ERROR!`

```
Error   C3867   'dlib::vector<long,2>::x': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member

Error   C2679   binary '<<': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'overloaded-function' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

Your help is appreciated!

Comment: What is the declaration of `part()`? What are `rect` and `parts` declared at? What is the declaration of `point`?

Comment: @EyasSH Added the full class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Looking at this compiler error more generally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37815641/visual-studio-2015-non-standard-syntax-use-to-create-a-pointer-to-member), it seems that `point::x()` is actually a member function, not a variable. So you should be using

```
cout << d.part(41).x() << endl; // :)
```

Why is the error so cryptic? `obj.func` could be seen as an attempt to use a function as a function-pointer variable (e.g. `&T::func`). Therefore you see compiler errors about:

1. Not knowing how to print (using `operator<<`) a method. Worse, a method with overrides, so its name is ambiguous.
2. Using `object.MethodName` is non-standard.