# cout a string member variable

Tags: c++, string, class, cout

I have a member variable that is string class type, and a member function that returns that member variable. The problem is that this returning value can't be used to output the string and I can't find out why this happens...

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class course {
public:
    std::string name = "hello";
    std::string get_name() {
        return name;
    }
};

int main() {
    course obj;
    std::cout << obj.get_name;
        return 0;
}
```

However, this code works ok:

```
std::string a = "hi";
std::cout << a;
```

Comment: Method call sould be `obj.get_name()`

Comment: You need to use the correct syntax for the function call. `std::cout << obj.get_name();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
std::cout << obj.get_name;
```

should be

```
std::cout << obj.get_name();
```

Because `get_name()` is a member function.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. It was a silly mistake. However, the compiler kept confusing me telling that I had to use a reference (¿?). Thank you all.

Comment: @HansGP What's your compiler (and its version)?

Comment: MVS Community v.15.3.5 was the compiler. Thanks for the suggestion, I'll check it.

Comment: @ Here is an awesome answer which explains why compiler tells me a reference is needed : )   https://stackoverflow.com/a/37816236/6949852

Comment: XD That explains the misterious message from my compiler. Very curious... Sometimes C++ has strange rules.

Comment: If you cannot understand msvc's compiler message, you can try gcc or clang, sometimes their error message will inspire you more directly

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the function through the object "obj" of class "course".Add parenthesis for calling.

```
std::cout << obj.get_name();
```